# What are these tonal markings called?

Tags: tones

Below are four tonal markings for 四川话:

[image: tonemarks]

- [image: firsttone] with a tone value of 55 (first tone)
- [image: secondtone] with a tone value of 21 (second tone)
- [image: thirdtone] with a tone value of 53 (third tone)
- [image: fourthtone] with a tone value of 213 (fourth tone)

I believe these are an older form of the tonal markings that can be found today, i.e:

- first tone: ˥ (55)
- second tone: ˨˩ (21)
- third tone: ˥˧ (53)
- fourth tone: ˨˩˧ (213)

which have probably been made obsolete. **Is my assumption correct?**

**If not what are the differences between these two different tonal markers?**

**What are these tonal markings called?**

**Can the first type of tonal markings be typed?** (above are all pngs)

---

edit: the second type seem to be called *tone letters*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_letter

but they are individually built - unlike the first kind which are morphed into one single "letter", if you will.

---

**edit 2**: these are definitely tone letters of some sort...

[image: search]
[image: search 2]

I searched `˨˩` in bing and look what get's displayed in the search bar above!

it's exactly the same as the second tone picture from above: [image: secondtone]

must be some sort of *font* thing going on to display this, in this way...

third tone works aswell:
[image: third tone]

and first tone:
[image: first tone]

but fourth tone doesn't really get the same results...
so what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a well-known issue to do with the *rendering* of contour tones in certain computer fonts. The Wikipedia article for [tone letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_letter) states that:

> The contour-tone letters are composed as sequences

In the "Modifier Tone Letters" block in the Unicode standard ([A700-A71F in Unicode 7.0](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA700.pdf)), only the level tone letters are provided. Hence any non-level tone letter is created by "smart rendering" capabilities within the program and within the font; it is usually classed as a type of [ligature](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CmplxRndExamples#3e655409). However, many (or most?) browsers cannot handle them, or only provide some of the ligatures.